# File does not belong to a cf project, please apply cf nature to project to which file belongs

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I have ColdFusion Builder 2016, started changes few cfm files and tried to execute the project but I do receive a popup showing "File does not belong to a cf project, please apply cf nature to project to which file belongs"

Could anybody please help on this issue

Comment: Sounds like you added a file outside of CF Builder and it does not like it. I might try something like right clicking and adding to project.